# Need help with error:: The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
dsgetQuesTypeID = objdalQuesTypeID.GetQuesTypeID(int.Parse(QuesTypeID)); //error here
```

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you see the int.Parse in metadata explorer

```
      //
    // Summary:
    //     Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer
    //     equivalent.
    //
    // **Parameters:
    //   s:
    //     A string containing a number to convert.**
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A 32-bit signed integer equivalent to the number contained in s.
    //

    public static int Parse(string s);
```

it requires a string input to be parsed , but QuesTypeID  is int so that's why no overloaded method is found so to correct the problem , you need to do following

```
int.Parse(QuesTypeID.ToString());
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply do 
dsgetQuesTypeID = objdalQuesTypeID.GetQuesTypeID(QuesTypeID); 
in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You have a member with the same name QuesTypeID as the name of the variable passed to the method. One is int and one is String. Try to rename the variable from the method to something else, like: quesTypeID. I think this would solve your problem. Also you should use Int.TryParse instead of Int.Parse.

Comment: The two members that look conflictinh are from different classes, so no conflict

Comment: @Dean Chalk, In the same bllques class there is: public int QuesTypeID and public int GetQuesTypeID(string QuesTypeID).

Answer (score 0):

You maybe passing `null` value into `GetQuesTypeID(string QuesTypeID)`

Comment: Passing null to Int.TryParse will trigger a runtime error of ArgumentNullException and not a compile time error. The current error states that the type of the variable that gets passed to the method is wrong and not it's value.